# Program unexpectedly quits for unknown reason (C++)

Tags: c++

For some reason, whenever I run [this program](http://pastie.org/799762) it exits at `permute(permutater, length, lenth);` . This doesn't happen whenever I comment out the line and the function doesn't even run. Any help?

Comment: Have you perhaps tried using a debugger?

Comment: It appears to be causing a segfault, which I believe has something to do with pointers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First thing I noticed - you're not initializing the index variable `hor`.

```
int permute(string permutater,int length,int lenth)
{
    int hor,hor2,marker;
    cout << length/lenth;
    for (marker=0;marker !=(length/lenth);marker++)
        {
            hor2 = permutater[hor];     // <== hor is not initialized
            permutater[hor] = permutater[hor-1];
            permutater[hor] = hor2;
            hor--;
            cout << permutater;
        }

}
```

Comment: This is the answer. Any old garbage could be in hor, pointing at any old bit of memory. Accessing that memory causes big trouble. Case closed.

Comment: Thank you very much, in hindsight ( as always) that was obvious -_-. Thanks for putting up with me.

Answer (score 2):

> hor2 = permutater[hor];

What's the value of `hor`?

Answer (score 2):

I got the following compile errors with MSVC

```
error C4716: 'permute' : must return a value
warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'hor' used
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't got a chance to run it yet, but did you notice that you're missing `return` in the `permute(string permutater,int length,int lenth)` function.

Also, please `#include <string>`